# Part invisible or badly visible in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, parts

Solved this too!

I redefined part using \addcontentsline, a command I didn't know, and found on the "Latex Companion" Manual (the best for Latex?). And I learned that you have to compile the code at least twice to get the desired result, a bit like for bibliographic reference.

Here is the solution, hoping it may be of interest for someone having the same problem, or, maybe, knowing a better solution:

```
 \renewcommand*\part[1]{
    \vspace*{160pt}
    \addtocounter{part}{1}
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    {\raggedleft 
        \Large \textsc{Parte} \Roman{part}
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 16pt
        \huge \uppercase{#1} \par\nobreak
    }
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\numberline{Parte \thepart} \\ \bfseries #1 }
%   \interlinepenalty 40
    \vskip 40pt
}
%
\titlecontents{part}
    [0pt\addvspace{20pt}]
    {\center\Large}
    {\center\thecontentslabel}
    {}
    {}
```

and here is the result; indeed the interline is a bit too close, I tried to add a vskip, with terrific results; the compiler crashed giving tens of red mistakes, apparently meaningless, and I had to cut the code, compile, then paste it again; hope to solve this last little problem sooner or later, it is a trifle any way:

[image: Table of contents]

Thank you

Paolo Bonavoglia

---

solved it; there was a mistake in a package with a renewcommand{part} giving this undesired effect.

But now I have a minor but boring problem

I simplified the titlecontents for part:

```
\titlecontents{part}
    [0pt\addvspace{20pt}]
    {{{\center\Large\thepart Parte}}\\ \Large\bfseries\thecontentslabel}
    {}
    {}
    {}
```

I tried several variants, but there is no way to separate part number from part label; and the result is always the following: (of course I want the part number on the first line)

[image]

Any idea?

---

I have defined the style of toc, everything works fine, but for some reason the part number and label do not appear in the table of contents; I tried this before the "\begin{document}":

```
\usepackage{titletoc}
...

\titlecontents{part}[0pt\addvspace{15pt}]
{{\makebox[3em]{{Parte \uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral\thepart}}}\newline}
  \Large\it\vskip-\baselineskip}{\thecontentspage}{}{}
```

and many other variants but the result is always the following, the toc ignores the part label and even the word "Parte" and jumps from chapter IV to chapter I (*by the way the red frames appear only using Acrobat Reader, while the pdf viewer of Texmaker 5.0.4 does not show them*):

[image]

Any hint? Any idea? Thank you

Paolo Bonavoglia

I add the below mentioned code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 

\usepackage[italian,greek]{babel} %%% 'french', etc.
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} % enhanced 

...

\usepackage{astyle}

\titlecontents{part}    % Another minimalist trial , it does not work either
    [0pt\addvspace{50pt}]
    {Parte \thepart {\contentslabel{3em}}}
    {}
    {}
    {}



\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt\addvspace{15pt}] %  This is working fine
{{\makebox[3em]{{\thecontentspage\hfill\ Capitolo \uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral\thecontentslabel}}}\newline}
  \Large\it\vskip-\baselineskip}{}{}{}

...

\begin{document}

...

%\pseudochapter{Indice}

\tableofcontents

...
...

\newpage

\part{Dispacci cifrati notevoli dall'archivio}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\chapter{Dispacci del Quattrocento}

\section{Ducale del Doge Michele Steno}\label{sec:ducaleSteno}
```

Comment: would you like to share your code as a minimal working example MWE

Comment: The book is now 3000 lines, I can only share a meaningful selection, with the segment corresponding to the above example

Comment: I appended it to the above question

Comment: Either the problem has been solved or not; perhaps the original question was solved, but you're adding something different, it seems. Since the original question had no answer, it's better if you clearly state the real problem you have now. Please, never add “SOLVED” to the title of questions.

Comment: OK, sorry, I'm new to this community, in other communities it is required to append a "solved" to communicate !!  So I will remove the SOLVED, But the original problem has been solved, now the part title is visible in the toc. Why do you say it had no answer??